# Using Generics in Interfaces with Circular Reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-core

Let's assume that I have 4 interfaces that look like the following:

```
interface IMain
{
  ICollection<ISub> Subs { get; set; }
}

interface ISub
{
  ICollection<ISubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

interface IPart
{
  ICollection<ISubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

interface ISubPart
{
  ISub Sub { get; set; }
  IPart Part { get; set; }
}
```

The end goal is for me to use these interfaces in one class library and implement them with classes in another.

If I try to implement the interfaces, the containing collection or object must still be the interface type rather than the class type. For instance:

```
public class Sub : ISub
{
  ICollection<ISubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework and EF Migrations. When I try to run the migration, it fails with the error:

```
The entity type 'MyProject.ISubPart' provided for the argument 'clrType' must be a reference type.
```

To attempt to circumvent this, I was thinking that I could pass the type in as a generic. That's easy to do until I get to ISubPart since ISubPart would have to generics that would have a circular reference back to the parent. So, something like this:

```
interface ISubPart<TSub, TPart>
  where TSub : class
  where TPart : class
{
  TSub Sub { get; set; }
  TPart Part { get; set; }
}
```

But, if ISub needed a generic type passed in to define ISubPart, then the generic for ISubPart would need to pass in the containing type as well. So, I'd almost need something like the following, which I know doesn't exist:

```
interface ISubPart<TSub<TSubPart>, TPart>
  where TSub : class
  where TSubPart : this
  where TPart : class
{
  TSub<TSubPart> Sub { get; set; }
  TPart Part { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my DBContext:

```
public abstract class MyDbContext : MyDbContext<Main, Sub, Part>
{
    protected MyDbContext() { }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
}

public abstract class MyDbContext<TMain, TSub, TPart> : DbContext
    where TMain : Main
    where TSub : Sub
    where TPart : Part
{
    protected MyDbContext() { }
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<TMain> Mains { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TSub> Subs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TPart> Parts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<SubPart>()
            .HasOne(o => o..Sub)
            .WithMany(m => m.SubParts as List<SubPart>)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.SubId);

        builder.Entity<SubPart>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Part)
            .WithMany(m => m.SubParts as List<SubPart>)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.SubId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I can't be the first person with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand the question

Comment: I've updated the question with more context.

Comment: You can't have a collection of interfaces in EF entities.

Comment: I know. So if I pass in a type, how could I pass the types down through the relationship chain?

Comment: What is `DbContextOptions`? And which EF-Version are we talking about specifically?

Comment: I'm targeting EF Core. I've added a sample. Look at your post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with EF Core you need to cast in the navigation expression:

```c#
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<SubPart>()
        .HasOne(o => (Sub)o.Sub)
        .WithMany(m => m.SubParts)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.Id);

    builder.Entity<SubPart>()
        .HasOne(o => (Part)o.Part)
        .WithMany(m => m.SubParts)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.Id);

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Comment: Getting further. Thanks Andriy! I'm going to post the solution back here when I have it working.

Comment: I'm having an issue with another navigation property. I'll hit you up on that one tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is working for me (including EF database creation with the concrete classes

```
interface IMain<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSubPart : ISubPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSub : ISub<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TPart : IPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
{
    ICollection<TSub> Subs { get; set; }
}

interface ISub<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSub : ISub<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TPart : IPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSubPart : ISubPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
{
    ICollection<TSubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

interface IPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TPart : IPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSub : ISub<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSubPart : ISubPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
{
    ICollection<TSubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

interface ISubPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSubPart : ISubPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TSub : ISub<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
    where TPart : IPart<TSub, TPart, TSubPart>
{
    TSub Sub { get; set; }
    TPart Part { get; set; }
}

class SubPart : ISubPart<Sub, Part, SubPart>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Sub Sub { get; set; }

    public Part Part { get; set; }
}

class Sub : ISub<Sub, Part, SubPart>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

class Part : IPart<Sub, Part, SubPart>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubPart> SubParts { get; set; }
}

class Main : IMain<Sub, Part, SubPart>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sub> Subs { get; set; }
}


class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Main> MainEntities { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the concrete implementations that are used by EF are not really free to support multiple types, only the interface can support some variety.

Comment: In the process of implementing this. I'll post back tomorrow.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you don't have any interface remaining in the EF Entities? As I said, I actually tested the code of my answer and I created an actual database file with EF 6.1.3 with it. So I think the problem is that you did something different from what I did.

Comment: I've added my Context to the post

Comment: I've dropped a sample project at http://jasongaylord.com/media/webapplication1.zip

Comment: @JasonN.Gaylord Ok, I re-checked, made a mistake... EF6 did create a migration, but it kindly ignored the interfaced properties `ISub<TSelf>` and `IPart<TSelf> Part`. Turning them into contrete types blows the generic model so much that I question the (even hypothetic) value of doing so. You won't get much flexibility anyway, but see my edit.

Comment: Actually I think this is developing in an XY problem... If you need abstraction from your entity classes, you need to have a separate model thats not database related at some point (maybe as wrapper around the database objects) or something completely different.

Comment: Andriy's post below got it. It was a navigation expression issue.